# UPS shipping method is not showing for magento v 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed the latest version `magento 1.9.0.1`.

We configure with the UPS shipping method but it is not showing at the checkout page. It is showing that:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

Any idea why do I get this message?

Comment: Any error logs on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

The live mode assumes https. If you are in a testing environment without https, switch the UPS shipping setting to test mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning logs on and enabling debug for UPS. Check your shipping log for any errors.